# Command or keyboard shortcut to clear command history in RStudio

Tags: r, rstudio

What is the command or keyboard shortcut equivalent to pressing the little broom button in the History window of RStudio which clears out the entire history buffer in the current session?

Note that I don't mean <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>L</kbd> which clears the command window, I mean clearing history which is accessed by pressing the up-arrow.

Comment: No, there really is no justification for clearing the history.  If you're trying to repeat previous commands via history, you're doing it wrong in the first place.  But if you absolutely **must** do this, create an empty text file, say "nohist.txt" and type `loadhistory('nohist.txt')` .

Comment: You may try `rstudioapi::executeCommand("clearHistory", quiet = TRUE)`

Comment: My 'justification' for clearing history is I don't want junk clogging my cloud - a 2020 problem. @GegznaV 's suggestion may be what I want, it works except for the 'quiet' part - confirmation dialog still pops up.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Function based on Carl Witthoft's helpful comment which clears the history (assumes you can write to the working directory):

```
clearhistory <- function() {
  write("", file=".blank")
  loadhistory(".blank")
  unlink(".blank")
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I guess there is no shortcut for the **broom** icon. Another method can be to manually delete the `.Rhistory` in the `RStudio` directory, but you have to restart the session to see this taking effect.

Answer (score 0):

I created a snippet. Go to Tools> Global Options> Code> Snippets> Edit Snippets and paste this in the R section and click Save. *There should be tabs after the first line or else the snippet won't work.* I like to use the `here` [package](https://here.r-lib.org/) which will find the file at the project level no matter where the current working directory is. You can change that part of the snippet if you wish. Change `h` to whatever you want.

```
snippet h
    `r eval(parse(text = '
    write("", file=here::here(".Rhistory"))
    loadhistory(here::here(".Rhistory"))
    '))`
```

Now all you have to do is type `h` then <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> to run the snippet and the code in it! Read more about snippets [here](https://support.rstudio.com/hc/en-us/articles/204463668-Code-Snippets?version=1.2.5033&mode=desktop)

Answer (score 0):

For MacOS R.app (R 3.6.3 GUI 1.70 El Capitan build (7735), there is and icon in the toolbar that you can click to show/hide R command history. When you see the command history, there's a button you can click to clear the history. This deletes all the history.