# How to clear R command history in RStudio?

Tags: r

I want to completely clear my R command history in RStudio. I'm talking about when I press the up and down arrow keys, not just clearing the console by clicking the broom.

I tried deleting the `.Rhistory` file in my working directory and restarting RStudio but the file keeps restoring itself. How do I completely get rid of it?

Comment: Have you checked https://community.rstudio.com/t/how-to-clear-the-r-environment/14303/6?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To clear the workspace environment use:

```
rm(list = ls())
```

To clear history of commands typed use:

```
clearhistory <- function() {
  write("", file=".blank")
  loadhistory(".blank")
  unlink(".blank")
}
clearhistory()
```

Reference:
This discussion might be helpful: [Command or keyboard shortcut to clear command history in RStudio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19754128/command-or-keyboard-shortcut-to-clear-command-history-in-rstudio)

Comment: I got `Error in clearhistory() : could not find function "clearhistory"`

Comment: Oh sorry, had to run it in the console. My bad.