# Which directory does history() function access in R?

Tags: r

I keep getting previous lines when I use `history()` in R.
I do not know exactly where R is getting those lines from, so I cannot delete it.

There is nothing in the work directory that is causing those lines.
How can I get rid of them or stop thos lines being automatically saved and keep appearing in my command history?

I keep getting previous lines when I use `history()` in R.
I do not know exactly where R is getting those lines from, so I cannot delete it.

There is nothing in the work directory that is causing those lines.
How can I get rid of them or stop thos lines being automatically saved and keep appearing in my command history?

Comment: Not sure which of these you've tried, but it _should_ be in the current working directory (`getwd()`) but might be in your home directory (try `Sys.getenv("HOME")`). If on Windows, I'd try both `c:/Users/yourusername` and `c:/Users/yourusername/Documents` just to be sure.

Answer (score 0):

The history is saved in the .Rhistory file for the session. This file exists in the working directory. You can save the history to another file using `savehistory('filename')` and open in notepad to access the contents. To clear the history, you can use the solution provided [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62888464/how-to-clear-r-command-history-in-rstudio)

Comment: Where is it written that history is saved in the `.Rdata` file? According to [`?history`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/utils/html/savehistory.html), `savehistory` defaults to the current working directory in a file named `".Rhistory"`.

Comment: Thank you @r2evans for the clarification. I have corrected my response.